Identity Framework with multiple DbContext
I'm currently working on an existing API and handles registration and login using the Identity Framework. I am still new to Identity Framework and OWIN. Originally, the DbContext and ApplicationUserManager were setup in Startup.Auth.cs:
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    }
}

The issue with this is that I could not specify the DB connection string dynamically here, I moved this code into the AccountController:
public HttpResponseMessage Register(string email, string username, string appName)
{
    string connection = ConnectionNames[appName];
    var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create(connection);

    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Set(db);
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Set(new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db)));

    var result = UserManager.Create(user, password);
    // ...
}

UserManager:
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

This works fine, but I don't think I'm making use of OWIN dependency injection anymore. I am thinking of creating instances instead of using OWIN, but will this cause any issues with Identity Framework? I believe I'll lose caching but are there any other concerns or alternate solutions?

You have an HTTP Client and a HTTP Server.  The HTTP Server connect to a backend Database (DBContext).  The Server needs to connect to the Database using the Client Credentials.  Your original code did not work because you created the DBContext in the Server Startup method which would of used the credentials of the app that started the Server (not the client credentials).  Moving the code into the HTTPResponse you are now using the Client Credentials and properly connecting to the Database.
